# Why is HTML elements is displayed as text?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a form builder website. After a form is built it must be saved in database. When the user clicks on a form name from the list of saved forms the form information is restored from database. One of the variables I will restore is the structure of the form. In javascript I wrote these lines of code:

```
var prefix_content='<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html lang="en-US">\n<head>\n<meta charset="UTF-8">\n<title>    </title>\n </head>\n<body>\n ';
var sufex_content=' \n</body></html>';
var dynamic_content=String(text_content);

document.write(prefix_content + dynamic_content + sufex_content  );
```

The variable dynamic_content contains the dynamic structure. 
The problem is that prefix_content and  sufex_content is displayed as html but dynamic_content is written in the page as text. Any one knows why is that or knows how to solve this problem.

Note: when I write the text in dynamic content statically between single quotes it is displayed as html not text.

Comment: Have you try to remove the String() operator? It is just a guess... I mean: document.write(prefix_content + text_content + sufex_content  );

Comment: No I can't because the type of text_content is object it cant be displayed if i remove string

Comment: Can you elaborate your need to do in such a manner? I don't see a proper use case of this. I may be wrong but I'd like to know your views on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "*HTML Elements displayed as text*"? What is the actual text that's displayed?

Comment: HAve YOu tried not to use document.write? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement

Comment: If the dynamic_content contains <p> shahd</p> it must be diplayed as shahd, but it is displayed as a text <p> shahd</p>

Comment: There was NOT to use ;)... Document write just writes to document, and does not modify the DOM tree. I know this isn;t an answer, but maybe switching to more modern method will give a good result.

Comment: but the content in prefix_content and sufex_content is displayed as dom which means that document.write do what i want

Comment: Sry my fault, You are right. But however according to that link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice, maybe You should try to modify DOM in another way? And You must double check what String projection really do for this undescribed type of object (text_content). I think this projection is the clue...

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222786/string-building-with-javascript-document-write

Comment: The issue depends on the value of the `text_content` variable, which is not set (or even declared) in the code or described in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're seeing the content retrieved from your database as plaintext, instead of HTML, its HTML entities are probably getting escaped somewhere along the way. Check the contents of your `text_content` variable (e.g. use `console.log(text_content)` and if you're seeing stuff like `&lt;div&gt;` instead of `<div>`, go on and find out where your escaping happens and either remove it or [manually unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
var prefix_content='<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html lang="en-US">\n<head>\n<meta charset="UTF-8">\n<title>    </title>\n </head>\n<body>\n ';
var sufex_content=' \n</body></html>';
var dynamic_content=String(text_content);
var parser = new DOMParser();
var el = parser.parseFromString(dynamic_content, "text/html");

document.write(prefix_content + el + sufex_content  );
```

Or you can try this too: **Using jQuery**

```
var dynamic_content=String(text_content);
var el = $.parseHTML( dynamic_content );
document.write(prefix_content + el + sufex_content  );
```

Comment: I tried it and this is what i've got [object HTMLDocument]

Comment: Why don't you use MIME: `text/html` (instead of `text/xml`)?

Comment: I used text/html and i've got [object HTMLDocument]

Comment: can you provide the result of String(text_content); ? Or can you create a fiddle .

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = "<div style='color:red;'>TEST</div>";


var prefix ='<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html lang="en-US">\n<head>\n<meta charset="UTF-8">\n<title>TEST</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n';
var suffix ='\n</body></html>';
var all = prefix + content + suffix;
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(all, "text/html");


console.log(doc.children[0].outerHTML);
```

Instead of `children[0]` you can also go for:

```
doc.documentElement.outerHTML
```

Results in:

```
<html lang="en-US"><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="color:red;">TEST</div>
</body></html>
```